# What parts of speech are "together" and "at the park"?

Tags: adverbs, parts-of-speech, parsing, adverbials

What parts of speech do you think 'together' and 'at the park' are and what do they describe in this sentence:

> Nobody saw Anna and John together at the park.

I'm thinking 'together' is a adverb, and 'at the park' is an adverbial phrase, but I'm not sure if it's describing 'together' or how they were not seen…

Comment: Modern grammar classifies "together" as a **preposition**. "At the park" is a **preposition phrase** functioning as a locative adjunct, i.e. a modifier in (and thus part of) the VP "saw Anna and John together at the park".

Comment: @BillJ Please expand on that in an answer.

Comment: @BillJ, if you call "together" a preposition, then it's worth mentioning that it's a strictly intransitive preposition, much like "here" and "there".  Intransitive prepositions are a modern idea, in contrast with the way that traditional grammar lumps those words into an overstuffed *adverb* class.  Also worth noting is that "Anna and John together" is a coherent phrase, showing that the preposition "together" plays an *adjectival* role in this context despite being traditionally classed as an adverb.

Comment: Yes, an intransitive preposition. And yes, in"Anna and John together at the park", the prep "together" modifies "Anna and John", and the PP "at the park" is a locative adjunct in clause structure.

Comment: I agree that it's an adverb, describing *saw*. The adverb phrase further clarifies how/when/where they were *seen together* -- **at the park**. I will not be providing this as an answer, though.